# How do you find the index/order integer of a table in an SQL database (Java)?

Tags: java, sql, database, oop, networking

I know that the following code below gives me the amount of tables in an SQL database (I use SQLite), but how would I get the "order" of a table so I can make a for loop to scan through all of them?

```
String numtables = "String sql = “SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'database’ ”;
pst = con.prepareStatement(numtables);
ResultSet numt = pst.executeQuery(numtables);
int num = ((Number) rs1.getObject(1)).intValue();
```

Comment: Your posted code does what now?

Comment: it gets the total number of tables in the database, at least, it's supposed to

Comment: You have non 7-bit ASCII quotes in there. I'd be surprised if Java or SQLite accepted them. But even if they do, I recommend to use the regular ones. Another thing, that's strange, is that your SQL query text actually contains a Java declaration/initialization of a variable. Is SQLite really accepting this and returning any result, let alone the expected? And why are you selecting `count(*)`, if you want some/all columns? Define them in the `SELECT` instead and then iterate over the result set.

Comment: Does that line make sense: `String numtables = "String sql = “SELECT ...`.  Looks like to many `"`.  As far as the order, please define the "order of a table" means to you and how it is calculated.

Comment: If you use `prepareStatement(Sting sql)`, then you need to use the no-arg version of `executeQuery()`. --- After calling `executeQuery()`, you must call `next()` on `numt` (or is it `rs1`?) before you can call `getObject(...)`

Comment: an order of the table is its placement from top to bottom in the order they were inserted. is there any way to do this?

Comment: *"I know that the following code below gives me the amount of tables"* No, the code gives you a **compilation error**.

Comment: so what would i do instead?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the [DatabaseMetaData Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct query should be (your talking about tables in a db)

```
SELECT * FROM my_db.sqlite_master WHERE type='table' order by rootpage;
```

The root page number for any index or table can be found by querying the *rootpage*.
They are not necessarily subsequent numbers.

then you can explore the result set with the usual

```
while (rs.next())
```

Of course take care of the syntax errors, and use the Preparestatement strategy as often as you can, as other suggest.

Comment: So could I automate this to make it universal for any kind of table with the same format, even though you said they're not necessarily subsequent? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Also, I've been told my way of finding the total amount of tables in a database leads to a compilation error, does this solution you described, essentially, let it "know" when to stop because it has went through all the table numbers? Like in a for loop?

Comment: Yes, this solution is universal, as far as you replace my_db with your db name. My solution will not give you any compilation error as far as you put the query inside a code without errors. Your favorite compiler will give you any useful hint about that.

Comment: You have no idea how grateful I am! I've been looking for a universal solution for so long! And the amount of tables in a database issue? How would I get an integer number for the amount of tables in my database? Because I want to be able to add as many tables as I like.

Comment: You are welcome set the answer as accepted if OK. To count you simply use:
`SELECT * FROM my_db.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';` it will return an integer with the number of tables.

Comment: One more thing, how would I do it the opposite way? Could I do something along the lines of (BS pseudocode, sorry) `String tablename = NameOfTableOfIndex(x);` to find the String name of a table of the index integer variable I assigned to the resultset of your solution?

Comment: Yes, you setup a counter variable (int counter = 0), and then when you iterate the resultset (with while(rs.next()) you make counter++ to know the number of that Table. You could also store this information once for all.